# python - Opening HTTPS links fails with urllib

Tags: python, ubuntu, https, beautifulsoup, urllib

I am having troubles opening links that have the **HTTPS** protocol, with urlib.
I'm running *python 2.7.1* in Ubuntu, using a home network (no proxy).

It returns and error all the time, it works if I change to HTTP, what am I missing here?

Code sample:

```
from BeautifulSoup import *

import urllib

url = "https://path/file.html"

html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
```

Returned Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "/home/.../links.py", line 4, in <module> html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
    html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 87, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 213, in open
    return getattr(self, name)(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 443, in open_https
    h.endheaders(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1048, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 892, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 854, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1273, in connect
    server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 352, in wrap_socket
    _context=self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 579, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 808, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
IOError: [Errno socket error] [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)
```

Comment: is it full error message ? There can be more useful information.

Comment: I updated it with the full error message. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I found out the solution for this, SSL code has to be set.

This part was missing in my code!

```
import requests
import json
import ssl

scontext = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
req = urllib.urlopen(url, context=scontext)
html = req.read()
```

`
This way it's possible to go through HTTPS websites

Answer (score 0):

It is not best answer.

I had this problem only with servers which use incorrect SSL certificate -  like `https://pygame.org/`.

In `request` there is option to disable certificate verification.

```
import requests

r = requests.get("https://pygame.org", verify=False)

html = r.content
```

With verification script doesn't work. Without verification script show warning but works.

But I didn't find this option in `urllib`.

Comment: Strange, my compiler says: *ImportError: No module named requests*, but I have the module installed (`pip3 install requests --upgrade`)

Comment: `pip3` installs for Python 3. use `pip` to install for Python 2.

Comment: true, sorry, but same with *pip*: `Requirement already up-to-date: requests in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages` Is it possible that I have python 2.7 and 3 installed at the same time and this is causing a mess? `python -V returns 2.7.10`

Comment: your `pip` is alias to `pip3` - try `pip2`. Or write `pip` and press `tab` twice to see all command started with `pip`

Comment: you can have 2.7 and 3 at the same time - and you should have commands `python`, `python2`, `python2.7`,  `python3` and `python3.4` - and `pip`, `pip2`, `pip2.7`, `pip3`, `pip3.4` :)

Comment: Thanks, but still the same, also with pip2 :/

Comment: it was the same issue, I found the solution, see my answer :) Thanks